# Install imagemagick with libheif on linux debian machines

Tags: apt, imagemagick

I can't get a straight answer to the following simple questions:

1. GENERAL CASE: how do you install an application via apt-get compiled with an optional library?
2. SPECIFIC CASE: I want to install imagemagick with the `libheif` option so that I can use it to convert `.heic` files to e.g. `.jpg`. What is the exact apt-get syntax to achieve this? With homebrew you just add `--with-libheif`, but I don't know what the debian convention is.

(I'm working on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)).

Comment: On Linux Mint 19 (Ubuntu clone, quite similar to Debian), the `libheif-examples` package contains tools, among which `heif-convert` can convert HEIF to JPG (or PNG). Its only option is quality of output, but you may chain it with imagemagick...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `libheif` and `libheif-dev` packages are not available for Debian Stretch. They are available for Buster but they are still in testing and not officially supported. As a result of this, installing `imagemagick` via `apt` will not provide conversion of heic files.

If you want to convert `.heic` files to another format such as `.jpeg` then you will need to compile `imagemagick` from source. First, get the code for `libheic` from here and compile it with the standard options:

https://github.com/strukturag/libheif/archive/v1.3.2.tar.gz

You can get Imagemagick here:

https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/archive/7.0.8-23.tar.gz

To get it to compile properly, I had to set the following variables:

```
export CFLAGS=-I/path/to/libheif/1.3.2/include
export LDFLAGS=-L/path/to/libheif/1.3.2/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/libheif/1.3.2/lib/pkgconfig
```

I also previously added the `bin` and `lib` directores of `libheif` to my respective `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` although it didn't work which is why I did the above.

I then ran configure with these options:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/imagemagick --with-heic=yes
```

Imagemagick will then compile with `heic` support. I was able to convert a .heic image to .jpeg afterwards with no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. To the general question; if those packages had been available for debian stretch, what would have been the syntax to install a build of imagemagick that incorporates those packages?

Comment: @Anastasius Vivaldus That would depend on how the package was built. The libraries for heic might have already been included or it might have been necessary to install them via apt separately. Either way, the functionality for the Imagemagick package from the Debian reops to recognize and convert would be available so it and the libheif package(if necessary) would just be installed via `apt`.

Comment: This worked for me (RHEL7). Paths for CFLAGS, LDFLAGS were in `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib`.